# AppleScript--item of list 1 contain Item of list 2

Tags: applescript

I want to write an inspection program.

If the item in List 2 is contained in List 1, the next item is checked. If not included, write this item to list 1.

```
set list_1 to {"万", "历", "阞", "劜", "办", "劝", "功", "加", "劢", "务", "动", "劣", "劤", "劥", "劦", "劧", "助", "劫", "劲", "劳", "励", "努", "劬", "劭", "労", "劰", "劮", "劯", "劾", "劼", "劻", "势", "効", "劷", "劵", "劶", "勆", "劽", "劺", "劸", "勃", "勉", "勋", "勇", "勅", "勁", "勂", "勀", "勊", "勄", "勈", "勐", "勍", "勑", "勌", "勏", "勎", "勒", "勔", "勖", "勚", "動", "勓", "募", "勛", "勞", "勜", "勤", "勣", "勢", "勦", "勠", "勡", "勧", "勨", "勩", "勱", "勥", "勭", "勫", "勪", "勬", "勲", "勯", "勮", "勵", "勳", "勶", "勴", "勷", "勸", "仂", "伤", "艻", "边", "夯", "叻", "另", "屴", "饬", "扐", "抛", "拋", "氻", "忇", "幼", "爋", "朸", "牞", "玏", "朂", "肋", "攰", "男", "穷", "虏", "糼", "竻", "觔", "辦", "赲", "釛", "飭", "鳨", "", "为"}

set list_2 to {"勇", "勫", "陸", "無", "給", "個", "幫", "爸", "姐"}

set numbet_ to 1
repeat
try

    repeat
        set get_ to get item number_ of list_2

        if list_1 contains get_ then
            set numbet_ to number_ + 1
            exit repeat
        else if list_1 does not contain get_ then
            set end of words_contained_in_piangpangwubi_and_pianpangcheshi to x4
            set numbet_ to number_ + 1
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat

on error
    exit repeat
end try
end repeat

list_1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
to putItems from M into L
    if M = {} then return

    script
        property array : L
        property list : M
    end script

    tell the result
        set [x, x_] to [item 1, rest] of its list
        if x is not in its array then set end of its array to x
        putItems from x_ into its array
    end tell
end putItems
```

Then:

```
putItems from list_2 into list_1
list_1
```

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of items in the list?

Comment: Although I don't know if your program has a limit on the number of list items. But if I use such a program, it will not go wrong. You can have a look

Comment: There isn't a builtin limitation on the number of items in a list.  However, there'll be a stack limitation based on memory size that limits the number of items in a list that can be used, but this will typically be of the order of a couple of hundred items, I should think.

Comment: There seem to be more than a few hundred in my list.～

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking.

Comment: I am not asking questions.

You said, "there'll be a stack limitation based on memory size that limits the number of items in a list that can be used, but this will typically be of the order of a couple of hundred items, I should think" "So I think the number of my projects may be bigger than what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know if your program has a limit on the number of list items. But if I use such a program, it will not go wrong. You can have a look

```
set words_contained_in_piangpangwubi to {"万", "历", "阞"}
set words_contained_in_piangpangwubi to {"万", "为", "历"}

repeat with item_number in words_contained_in_piangpangcheshi
set booleanlist to {}
repeat with item_number_2 in words_contained_in_piangpangwubi

    if contents of item_number_2 is not contents of item_number then
        set end of booleanlist to true
    end if

    if contents of item_number_2 is contents of item_number then
        set end of booleanlist to false
    end if

end repeat
set booleanlist_number to 0
repeat with booleanlist_number_2 in booleanlist
    if contents of booleanlist_number_2 is true then
        set booleanlist_number to booleanlist_number + 1
    end if
    if contents of booleanlist_number_2 is false then
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat

if booleanlist_number = (count item of words_contained_in_piangpangwubi) then
    set end of words_contained_in_piangpangwubi to contents of item_number
end if

end repeat
words_contained_in_piangpangwubi
```